# Percussion and accompaniment application for Linux platforms

Tags: linux, open-source, music, music-production

I am a piano player. I had a keyboard that had the feature to add percussion and accompaniment when giving the chords and selecting the rhythm (e.g. *Ballad*).

I switched to a digital piano that is awesome but doesn't have this feature.

Is there any application that does this?

Features:

- a desktop application
- open source
- works on Linux
- nice rhythms and accompaniments
- easy to use (just put the chords in and get the sounds)
- export the result to an audio file format (not midi)
- would be great if it could be synced with Ardour

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest that you tale a look at [Hydrogen](http://www.hydrogen-music.org/hcms/node/2):

- a desktop & open source application - **Yes to both**
- should work on Linux platforms - **Linux specific.** *but there are OSX and Windows builds.*
- nice rhythms and accompaniments - *You can put together your own sequences to meet your requirements - you can also download sequences that others have built.*
- easy to use (just put the chords and get the sounds) - hard to quantify easy
- should be able to export the result in an audio file format (not midi) - *can  export to wav, aiff, flac, ogg as well as midi*
- would be really great if it could be synced with Ardour - *possibly you could always suggest it or develop it yourself.*

Main Window Screenshot from website:
[image: Main Window]

Comment: Hydrogen can be synced with Ardour, but could you add how can I add pre-built rhythms and accompaniments giving the chords? Thanks!

Comment: You can download a range of pre-built rhythms & accompaniments from the website then load them from the sound library.

Comment: Can you add an example how can I do that?  Also, where can I find these rhythms & accompaniaments?

Comment: Have your read the online documentation or looked at the wiki?  You will find both there!

Answer (score 0):

The software I develop, [JJazzLab](https://www.jjazzlab.com), is a new free and open-source based application which fullfills **all your requirements**, except the syncing with Ardour.

It's simple: you type in a few chords, pick up a style, and it generates the accompaniment. You can refine the accompaniment if needed. It uses Yamaha style files, thousands of them can be found for free on the web.

The export-to-audio feature is not built-in within JJazzLab since it's a Midi app., but it's simple to do when used with FluidSynth (see FluidSynth -F option).

[image]